# Issues trying to add a href statment with PHP into a PHP Echo Statement

Tags: php, conditional-tags

Having issues with a line of code that's in an if/else statement. It's PHP so I should be using php echo to make it work but I can't seem to get the coding correct. Here's what it should be originally;

```
<?php echo get_permalink( get_the_ID() ); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo get_the_title( get_the_ID() ); ?>
```

and here what I've done to it (that's wrong):

```
<?php echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( get_the_ID() );.'" rel="'bookmark'" title="'get_the_title( get_the_ID() )'">'; } ?>
```

Comment: Can you give a little more code to show ?

Comment: That's all I got.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. If you know what it should be, why is there a problem? What file is this code in? Paste a larger block, including the if structure.

Comment: You are missing concatenate operator `.` before and after `get_the_title()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. However, in the second line of code you have a closing bracket at the end, but there is no opening bracket in your code. Maybe that's the problem?